# Writing test for before delete trigger

Tags: unit-test

I have a trigger that fires when a user tries to delete a child object that is associated to a parent object.

So, in my test class, I set up my child and parent objects and relate them. Then I try to delete the child object, and obviously it fails.

But, the delete should fail, but how would I check that in the test class?

my code in the test class says:

```
List<Child__c> testChildren = SetupTestData.Children, //creates a number of children
List<Parent__c> testParents = SetupTestData.Parents; //creates a number of parents with relation to children
insert testChildren;
insert testParents;

List<Child__c> childToDelete = new List<Child__c>([SELECT id FROM Child__c LIMIT 1]);

delete childToDelete;
```

How do I need to amend my test code?
Tia.

Comment: you should write your testmethod to test batch deletes (avoid limit 1 in the SOQL) as batch deletes are possible in data loader or other api-type interactions - I also don't see how you can insert children before parents as you need the ids of the parents in order to insert a child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the delete inside a try/catch along with a couple of (otherwise silly) assertions, like so

```
try {  
    delete childToDelete;  
    System.Assert(false, 'This was supposed to fail');  
}catch(DMLException e){  
    System.assert(true, 'Deletion failed appropriately');
}
```

Although, you'd probably want to use a better/real assertion inside that catch block.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi. Please check the below code.

```
    boolean checkError;

    Test.startTest();

    try {

        delete childToDelete;

        checkError = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        checkError = true;
    }

    Test.stopTest();

    System.assert(checkError);
```

Here, we want the code to throw an exception when someone tries to delete the record having related detail records. So, checkError is set to true if exception is thrown(record has related detail record(s)), and if record is deleted the checkError value will be false. We can check this value in assert later. If it is true, record is not deleted.